# Keras: model.evaluate() on training and val set differ from the acc and val_acc after last training epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

After the last training epoch, I get this output:

```
Epoch 100/100
89254/89254 - 24s - loss: 0.1935 - acc: 0.9281 - val_loss: 0.2182 - val_acc: 0.9219
```

But the problem is, once I conduct `model.evaluate()` on training data and validation data, I get different results:

```
Train accuracy: 0.929661
Validation accuracy: 0.921859
```

How does this make sense? And why does parameter `batch_size` exist for the `model.evaluate()` function despite test mode? https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate
If I have trained the model in batches, would I need to define the batch size for test mode as well?

Comment: Your second question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911321/why-does-prediction-needs-batch-size-in-keras/37912576#37912576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it makes sense, to start, any metric/loss produced in the training set on the progress bar is computed as a running mean over training batches, where the weights are changing due to gradient descent. This means that training metrics will never match the ones computed with `model.evaluate()`, as in that case weights are constant and not changing.

About validation metrics, they do match, its just that the `keras` progress bar prints only four significant digits, and you printed more.

About batch size, I already commented that basically it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911321/why-does-prediction-needs-batch-size-in-keras/37912576#37912576). Keras uses batches because you cannot make a prediction on a whole dataset at a time, that would probably use too much memory